# HTML5/JQuery Data Attribute Isolation

Tags: javascript, jquery

### [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w0fxp636/)

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.SiteNav>li>a').length) {
    if ($(e.target).is("[data-trigger='active']")) {
      alert('true');
    }
  }
});
```

I'm using `if ($(e.target).closest('.SiteNav>li>a').length) {` so that the user can either click on the `<a></a>` or anything within the `<a></a>` such as the `<i></i>`.

The reply button will take the user to the reply section/page whereas the other button shows additional options such as 'Reply', 'Reply All' and 'Forward' however upon this menu being shown, I want to set this `data-trigger="active"` on the drop down to 'deactive' and have the 'active' placed on the `<li></li>` instead.

The problem I am having is finding where the `data-trigger="active"` is.

The below script *might* not make much sense, it is where I have based my JSFiddle snippet from my larger script;

```
if ($(e.target).closest('.SiteNav>li>a').length) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.SiteNav>li>a').length.is("[data-trigger='active']")) {
        alert('true');
    }
    var id = $(e.target).closest('li').data('id');
    $(".SiteNav>li>a:not([data-link='" + id + "'])").removeClass('hover sideHover active');
    $(".SiteNav>li>ul:not([data-drop='" + id + "'])").hide();

    if (!$(e.target).closest('li').find('ul').is(':visible')) {
        $(".SiteNav [data-link='" + id + "']").addClass('active');
        $(".SiteNav [data-drop='" + id + "']").show();
    } else {
        $(".SiteNav [data-link='" + id + "']").removeClass('active');
        $(".SiteNav [data-drop='" + id + "']").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: On the second line, shouldn't that be `.is` instead of `.length.is`?

Comment: @4castle Thank you for your input, I tried this, was actually my original thought. only managed to get it working for the link and not within so far.

Comment: @TimMarshall I have modified your jsfiddle based on @4castle's comment, and it seems to function in a manner consistent with your need.  Could you please explain what you expect to see when you click on either the anchor or `<i>` elements?  New jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w0fxp636/1/

Comment: @Pred I was failing to call for `.closest('.SiteNav>li>a')` Should I give up now or?... Sometimes I do question why I don't get downrated on stupid questions I've asked whilst been working all day, you just don't see the obvious!

Comment: @Pred do you know if I can do the following to see if either one has the data? `.closest('.SiteNav>li>a', '.SiteNav>li')` or something similar?

Comment: @TimMarshall You could use something like `$(e.target).closest("[data-trigger='active']")` to give you the active element.  You can use it in an "if" statement to see whether an active element exists.

Comment: @Pred I've got it working via `if ($(e.target).closest('.SiteNav>li>a').is("[data-trigger='active']") || $(e.target).closest('.SiteNav>li').is("[data-trigger='active']")) {` just seems kind of long.

Comment: @TimMarshall Great! Looks good. See if my previous post will work for you too.  Also, you may benefit from simply giving each element a class-name, then binding a "click" action to a function: $('.my-list-item').on('click', function() { alert('Hello World!'); })